# Are there any philosophers after Kant but before Peirce that developed the Kantian concept of schema further?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy, kant

I was reading Peirce's writings on schemata and I was wondering if there was any other known philosopher before him who tried to use or extend schemata in his work.

> Are there any philosophers after Kant but before Peirce that
> developed the Kantian concept of schema further?

Comment: Scaglia has a comprehensive review of reception of Kant's schematism in his book [Kant´s Notion of a Transcendental Schema](https://www.peterlang.com/view/9783631821459/html/ch17.xhtml), from Fichte and Schelling to neo-Kantians and 20th century psychology. Much of it is more of criticism and/or replacement than "development", but Schelling, Schleiermacher and Fries are more constructive. Bergson, Peirce's contemporary, influenced reception of the schematism by modern psychologists through Piaget.

Comment: @Conifold ah thank you. Can you answer my other recent questions about Peirce?